# duplicate sites one wordpress one flash

Tags: html, flash, wordpress, duplicates

I would like to have a link on my wordpress site to view a flash version of the same site. Could it be done by creating a subdomain for the flash site and using robots.txt to hide the flash site from search engines to avoid duplicate content. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: your comment should have gone to the answer, not to your question

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes you could do that but why do you need to hide it from the bots?  If it's flash they most likely won't index anything other than the meta information, so just don't populate any of that and you should be ok.